# Store SHA256 hash in Access Database

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, sha

I'm trying to figure out how to store a hash in my Access Database. Now I have generated a hash by salting a user password with the User ID (not highly secure I know, but plenty for my purposes). I have also stored the hashed values in the database as Base64 strings (manually, I haven't yet developed the module to do that automatically), however, when I go to retrieve the hash from the database I receive the hex code in place of the string. I know that the string is stored in the database since I stored it there manually so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

This is the code for the login button:

```
Sub prcLogin()
        'Log User in

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim blnCorrect As Boolean

        'Fill DataSet with login details
        prcConnectSet("SELECT * FROM Parent", "User", ds)

        strUser = txtUser.Text

        'Ensure username field is not blank
        If strUser <> "" Then

            'Search for the user
            For Each Row In ds.Tables("User").Rows
                Dim HashedPass As String = fncComputeHash(txtPass.Text & strUser)
                Dim ContainedPass As String = Row.Item(3)
                'Validate user
                If strUser = Row.Item(0) Then
                    If HashedPass = Row.Item(3) Then
                        blnCorrect = True
                        lblLoggedAs.Text = Row.Item(1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    blnCorrect = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

And this is the code for the hash calculator:

```
    Function fncComputeHash(ByVal PasswordField As String) As String
        Dim Hasher As New SHA256CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(PasswordField)))

    End Function
```

But when I run this instead of returning a value like "rlzhYoiO4+vpdJdsrFq5Sj9VBJ+FFYhIg9V5+z+jeNI=" which I stored in the database, it returns a value like "5C6BED0D94B9BE8AFBC5C8CAC1E9D4BE03F556917C2611EC56F4E6F341EF60D9". Now how do I get around this? Am I storing the values incorrectly? Should I store them as a byte array? If so, how do I do that? Or am I retrieving the values incorrectly? Or are those ok and should I be converting the value once I get it back from the database?

I'm very new to this whole encryption lark and even authentication so if I'm doing something stupid do tell me.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'm using the "Text" data type in Access.

**Edit 2:** Sorry I understand the confusion now. I'm storing only the hash! Not the plaintext password. So it's vital the hash received from the database is in the same format as that from the user id and password.

**Edit 3:** OK Thanks guys, I've solved it. I needed to convert it to a hex string using the SoapHexBinary function.

Comment: what data type are you using to store the hash in the db?

Comment: Sorry for the vb tag. That was an accident.

Comment: u can't retrieve the original password from the hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed. The "SoapHexBinary" function is what I need. Here is an example:

```
Function fncComputeHash(ByVal PasswordField As String) As String
    'Compute SHA-256 Hash value

    Dim Hasher As New SHA256CryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim encoder As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim shb As New SoapHexBinary(Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(PasswordField)))

    Return shb.ToString

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is not intended behaviour? Does it return the same hash if you pass the same value? IF yes, then you've achieved your purpose. You've got a one way hashed string of the username and password.

comparing
so you retrieve the has from database and store the hash from the table

get the userid and password from database and compute the hash

So basically, when the user types in his username, you fetch his userid from database
Calculate the has from the provided password 
and you've got the two hashes.

```
databasehash=gethashfromdatabase(user_id)
receviedhash=computehash(user_id,password)
```

now, you can compare the two.

note: If you want more explanation on fetching data from database or getting user_id from the form, I suggest posting a new question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand it's the same data encoded differently, however how do I convert one to the other so that I can compare them?

Comment: Problem is I'm not storing the password and user id, just the hash value. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with strong encryption, strong hashes (such as SHA1) it is critical that you understand that all of them are defined to work on strings of octets, which are usually arrays of unsigned characters. They are not "strings" as used by popular programming languages.

What you are seeing, "5C6BED..." is simply a hexadecimal encoding of the octets. Just call that a string, and store it, and then retrieve it, and convert back to the raw value for processing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is I don't have that as a string before I add it to the database. When I store it is a Base64 string and when I get it back it's a hexadecimal string. Are you suggesting I convert it to hex before storing it? If so how do I do that?